# C# refactor if-else statement code

Tags: c#, refactoring

Please check out my following code...

```
public enum LogType
{
    Debug,
    Info,
    Warn,
    Error,
    Fatal
}

private static readonly ILog log = 
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

public void LogError(LogType logtype, string message)
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    if (logtype == LogType.Debug)
        log.Debug(message);
    else if (logtype == LogType.Error)
        log.Error(message);
}
```

I do not like all the above if-else statements and believe that there is a cleaner way to write this. How could I refactor it? log class has different methods for Debug, Error etc. etc.

I would like to make a single call to a method have it automatically take care of it.

```
LogMyError(LogType.Debug, "I am just logging here");
```

How can I do such a thing? I prefer to stay away from switch statement. I am looking for a clean object oriented approach.

Comment: Isn't that what you're already doing?

Comment: Apart from the switch block, I wouldn't spend too much time on thinking about a refactoring pattern if its only the 2 options to choose from. Its perfectly readable this way.

Comment: I too don't see the reason for any changes - for refactoring or any design improvement usually you have to have a reason why, what is that you're trying to 'solve' or improve, make simpler etc. I don't see that here, one simple method does it already, use switch if more 'types'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary<LogType,Action<string>>` to hold what action to perform for each enumeration value, then just call the delegate.

```
var logActions = new Dictionary<LogType,Action<string>>();
logActions.Add(LogType.Debug, log.Debug);
...

logActions[logtype](message);
```

---

Update:

This is all overkill if you do only have a small number of branches on your `if` statements. I would use this method for 5+ such ifs.

Comment: Oded.. thanks.. can I get code example if possible.. I am new to this.

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner - Example given, though it assumes you already have an instance of `log` somewhere.

Comment: Seems a bit like overkill if you know in advance that there are only going to be two values, error and debug.

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner - Also take a look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10035869/1583) by dasblinkenlight, using lambdas.

Comment: @Servy - Yes, though I am assuming that was simply an _example_ and there are more enum options.

Comment: @Oded: just deleted :) ha ha... :D

Comment: I like it - it's elegant! However, the implementor had best ensure all values of the enum are implemented, or use Dictionary.Contains first in case any callers use an enum value not covered.

Comment: @dash - Yes, this is illustrative only.

Comment: @Tigran - I agree, assuming the code is as posted. I am not making that assumption, but assuming there are many `if`s that were not posted.

Comment: Thanks Oded.. I implemented your approach and its much cleaner.

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner - Take a look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10036020/1583) by Eric Lippert, where an inheritance approach is used (this is a better approach if you have several different methods to call).

Answer (score 16):

Your code is perfectly fine as it is; I would not change it.

However, it is instructive to think about how you *would* do this if you wanted to be more "object oriented" about it. Let's just consider two of your cases; the others you can easily see how they would be implemented:

```
public abstract class LogType
{
    public static readonly LogType Debug = new LogTypeDebug();
    public static readonly LogType Error = new LogTypeError();

    private LogType() {} // Prevent anyone else from making one.

    public abstract void LogMessage(ILog logger, string message);

    private sealed class LogTypeDebug: LogType
    {
        public override void LogMessage(ILog logger, string message)
        {
            logger.Debug(message);
        }
    }

    private sealed class LogTypeError: LogType
    {
        public override void LogMessage(ILog logger, string message)
        {
            logger.Error(message);
        }
    }
}
...

//Obtain the log object the way you prefer.
private static readonly ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

public void LogError(LogType logtype, string message)
{
    logtype.LogMessage(log, message);
}
```

The call site does not change at all! It still looks like:

```
LogError(LogType.Debug, "my message");
```

And there you go: no `if` or `switch` statements at all!  The "switch on the type" code has been moved *into the virtual function table*, which is where it belongs in object-oriented code.

A nice side effect of this technique is *you never need to worry about someone casting an integer to an unsupported value of your enumerated type*. The *only* possible values for a variable of type LogType are null or a reference to one of the singletons.

Comment: This is absolutely the approach I would take if I had more than one `Action<T>` to switch on.

Comment: Eric, it looks like my GetLogger is different than your GetLogger

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner: And that is relevant to the question how? I'm not following your train of thought here. The point of the answer was to demonstrate to you how to do this task in an object-oriented fashion; is it unclear in some way?

Comment: @EricLippert I think OP is a beginner so he didn't realize that in your code sample provided, it's immaterial how the actual log object is obtained. I have taken the liberty to adjust your code sample so that it's easier for him to follow through code, I hope it's okie.

Comment: Keeping aside the technique of avoiding 'if/else' constructs, I think OP's approach is not right. The ILog interface defines method as Info, Debug, Warn etc. I think OP should use these methods directly in his code instead of making another wrapper method. E.g. Let's say you were to download a file from FTP server. After a file is downloaded, you can use Info() method to log the success. And if an exception occurs, you use Error method (which takes Exception) to log the error.

Answer (score 5):

Imo, there is no any apparent reasons to change anything in your code.
The function is clear, and makes clear `if/else` definition. 
Function declaration lets you use it in a way you just *want* use it.

So I would not change anything in the code I see.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [switch block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
switch (logtype)
{
    case LogType.Debug:
        log.Debug(message);
        break;

    case LogType.Error:
        log.Error(message);
        break;

    //more cases here as needed...

    default:
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("logtype");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's always the [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) statement:

```
switch (logtype)
{
    case LogType.Debug:
        log.Debug(message);
        break;
    case LogType.Error:
        log.Error(message);
        break;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a `switch` or create a dictionary with the `LogType` as key and the corresponding `LogXXXX` method as a value - an `Action<string>`, and then do

```
myDictionary[logType](message);
```